# Upgrading libphonenumber-android from 8.12.52 to 8.13.18 causes Error while merging dex archives

Tags: android, kotlin, android-multidex, libphonenumber

I have an android app, and when I update past 8.13.17 I get:

Error while merging dex archives

Execution failed for task ':app:multiDexListAppName.

> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
> Error while merging dex archives:

I have used:

resolutionStrategy.force 'io.michaelrocks:libphonenumber-android:8.13.18'

If I don't use that, I get:

> Conflict(s) found for the following module(s):
> - io.michaelrocks:libphonenumber-android between versions 8.13.18 and 8.12.52

(8.12.52 was the last version I was on)

Any ideas how to resolve this or why it breaks past that version number. The app is quite old but still, it seems odd and is not an easy error message to debug?

Any help supremely appricated...